# Is it possible to filter addresses in the CC field but not in the TO field?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

What I'm trying to do is setup a rule in Outlook 2010 that filters on a specific e-mail address in the `CC` field but not in the `To` field. For example, all mail with To:example@blah.com should move to a folder called ToEmails. All mail with CC:example@blah.com should move to a folder called CCEmails.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

- Create a new rule
- Choose `Start from a blank rule` -- check messages when they arrive
- On the next 'conditions' page, choose `Where my name is in the To box`
- Click next
- Now choose `Move to a specified folder` and choose the folder

Create another new rule just the same, except choose `Where my name is in the Cc box`